# Create Parent-Child view from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchy

I got following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Equipment (Id int,Name varchar(20),SubAreaId int);

INSERT INTO Equipment (Id, Name ,SubAreaId)
VALUES  (1, 'EquipmentA',1),
        (2, 'EquipmentB',1),
        (3, 'EquipmentC',2),
        (4, 'EquipmentD',2);

CREATE TABLE SubArea (Id int,Name varchar(20),AreaId int);

INSERT INTO SubArea (Id,Name,AreaId)
VALUES  (1, 'SubAreaA',1),
        (2, 'SubAreaB',2),
        (3, 'SubAreaC',2);
        
CREATE TABLE Area (Id int,Name varchar(20),SiteId int);

INSERT INTO Area (Id,Name,SiteId)
VALUES  (1, 'AreaA',1),
        (2, 'AreaB',1),     
        (3, 'AreaC',1);        
        
CREATE TABLE Site (Id int,Name varchar(20));
INSERT INTO Site (Id,Name)
VALUES  (1, 'Site');
```

Would like to get a view that displays:

[image]

Link to SQl Fiddle where I created schema:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/53d1ce/2

> Edit: Added AreaC and SubAreaC which should not be displayed in the view as they are not connected to any equipment

Answer (score 0):

This is a `union all`:

```
select s.name, a.name
from area a join
     site s
     on a.siteid = s.id
union all
select a.name, sa.name
from subarea sa join
     area s
     on sa.areaid = a.id
union all
select sa.name, e.name
from equipment e join
     subarea sa
     on sa.subareaid = sa.id;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, unfortunately I want to display whole hierarchy for  only connected Equipment. I'm going to modify my schema to reflect this.